# Custom Background image for a Textview

Tags: android

I am trying to create clickable textbox that highlights like a listview item when pressed. I have my own background image that i want to use so i cannot use

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Is there a way i can achieve the blue "glow" affect when i click on the textbox while using my own background image for the textbox? Currently, my textview looks like:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/title"
          style="@style/ListSeparatorTextViewStyle"
          android:paddingLeft="10dip"
          android:paddingRight="10dip"
          android:focusable="true"/>
```

UPDATE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
          android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_section_divider_holo_custom"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: For `TextView`s you'll have to provide the two images (normal and highlighted) and use a selector to change them on `TextView` pressed.

Comment: Another suggestion from me - Make the Text View a Button (it has those two states built in). It will be easily manipulated, but it depends from your needs.

Comment: Can you give an example snippet on how i can achieve your first suggestion?

Comment: the code for the selector is below (in the Answer of @solo). Now you should give it a name and set it as the drawable resource of the background attribute of the xml ot the TextView :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a drawable for background of textview same below

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item   android:state_pressed="true" ><!-- this drawable display when you press textView -->
<shape  android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient android:startColor="#fa7905"
          android:endColor="#fcc96b"
          android:angle="90"
></gradient>
</shape>
</item>

<item android:drawable="your drawable">
<!-- this drawable show when you dont press textview -->
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: wont this interfere with my other drawable? How do i use this selector?

Comment: I get an error when i do this. android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class <unknown>. I have named your selector list_selector in an xml file and tried to set it as the background by setting android:background="@layout/list_selector" tag on my textview

Comment: you should place it in drawable folder

Comment: That did not make a difference

Comment: you set <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> tag in your file??

Comment: I have updated my question to show you the content of that selector file

Comment: dont exist any attribute android:background for item tag you only can use android:drawable="" and @android:drawable/ for item tag

Comment: Ah that seems to have been the problem. Would you happen to know the colors to make it select like a listview item?